# what is an internal iso 27001 technical auditor?

Tags: penetration-test, audit, iso27000

i have been recently hired by an ISO 27001 certified company as an **" internal ISO technical auditor"**.

My employer told me that my job is described as follow:

- this job is created because of the need of a technical resource who will take care of technical issues not organisational issues
- i am attached to the ISO team and not to the IT team
- i am going to take care of everything related to pentesting, log review, configurtation review, securing electronic threads, backup , ...
- defining physical and logical security measures that should be taken are not in my scope

i am a little bit confused and  can't really understand my responsabilites, moreover i didn't find such job in the ISO norm.

i need to know if there is a such well known job , and what are it's real responabilites

Thanks

Comment: This is a conversation to have with your employer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're responsibilities is to verify on on-going basis if your company is adhering to the ISO27001. So basically your third point describes what you will be doing: **reviews**.

Basically you are an auditor, which indeed means you are NOT part of the IT department, but the audit department. This is to ensure independence and objectiveness as no-one of the upper management in the IT department should be able to pressure you based on performance reviews for instance.